# SSL certificate warning

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

We have an installed SSL certificate on our website. First time user needs to install this certificate (accept it) on their browsers. Is there way to disable it?

I think it might be possible with apache conf or .htaccess file setting SSL path in it.

Can anyone did this and can paste me the settings here.

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard for us to replicate a problem you are having with minimal details. Maybe this is something to work out with your SSL cert company. It's probably not best to release details of the cert that you have been issued.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your certificate is signed incorrectly or for the wrong domain. Most browsers today don't ask about security certificates if they're completely valid.